# The derived $\mathscr{der}(Y)$ of some set $Y$ is empty iff $Y$ is a set of isolated point.

Tags: general-topology

Let be $X$ a topological space and let be $Y\subseteq X$ such that $\mathscr{der}(Y)=\varnothing$: so for any neighborhood $I_y$ of $y\in Y $ it result that $I_y\cap Y={y}$ and so Y is a set of isolated point. Now of $Y$ is a set of isolated point clearly none of its point could be a accumulation point: anyway if $x\notin Y$ how prove that for any its neighborhood $I_x$ it result that $I_x\cap Y=\varnothing$?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: what is $der(Y)$ ? the set of limits points ?

Comment: @Surb Yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

der($Y$) is empty iff $Y$ is a closed discrete subspace of $X$.

(1). If der($Y$) is empty: (i). Any   $p\in \overline Y$ \ $Y$ would belong to der($Y$). So $\overline Y=Y.$ (ii). Any $y\in Y$ has an open nbhd $U_y$ (in the space $X$) such that $U_y\cap Y=\{y\},$ so $\{y\}$ is open in the subpace topology on $Y$.

(2).If $Y$ is a closed discrete subspace of $X$:  (iii). If $y\in Y$ then $\{y\}$  is open in the subspace $Y$ so there exists some open subset $U_y$ of the space $X$ such that $U_y\cap Y=\{y\},$ so $y\not\in$ der($Y$). (iv). If $x\in X$ \ $Y$ then $X\setminus Y=X$ \ $\overline Y$ is a nbhd of $x$ which is disjoint from $Y,$ so $x\not \in$ der($Y$).

Example. Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and let $Y=\Bbb N.$

Note that if der($Y$) is empty then members of $Y$ are isolated points in the space $Y$ but  not necessarily isolated points of  $X$.

Answer (score 4):

Not true in general.

Let  $a\neq b$ and $\tau=\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Then $\tau$ is topology on $X=\{a,b\}$.

$Y=\{a\}$ is a set of isolated points but evidently $b$ is a limit point of $Y$ so that $\mathsf{der}(Y)\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. Let us consider $\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the discrete topology and let $X=\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$ as the one point compactification of such a space ($X$ is homeomorphic to a convergent sequence). Let $Y=\mathbb{N}\subset X$. Since the subspace topology on $Y$ is equivalent to the discrete topology, all the points of $Y$ are isolated points. On the other hand  the limit point $\{\infty\}$ is an accumulation point for $Y$, therefore each neighborhood of $\{\infty\}$ intersects $Y$.